# OneSignal (iOS) - didReceiveNotificationRequest not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, onesignal, remote-notifications

I followed OneSignal's set up guide, added an extension all named properly and have this file that they provided:

```
#import <OneSignal/OneSignal.h>

#import "NotificationService.h"

@interface NotificationService ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) void (^contentHandler)(UNNotificationContent *contentToDeliver);
@property (nonatomic, strong) UNNotificationRequest *receivedRequest;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UNMutableNotificationContent *bestAttemptContent;

@end

@implementation NotificationService

- (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent * _Nonnull))contentHandler {


    self.receivedRequest = request;
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler;
    self.bestAttemptContent = [request.content mutableCopy];

    [OneSignal didReceiveNotificationExtensionRequest:self.receivedRequest withMutableNotificationContent:self.bestAttemptContent];

    self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent);
}

- (void)serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire {
    // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
    // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.

    [OneSignal serviceExtensionTimeWillExpireRequest:self.receivedRequest withMutableNotificationContent:self.bestAttemptContent];

    self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent);
}
@end
```

Also copied all their code for AppDelegate as outlined in their setup guide here:
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup plus some other code to create the 'center' variable as someone recommended on github. Adding this instance in AppDelegate did make it so that 'didReceiveRemoteNotification' gets called, but not didReceiveNotificationExtensionRequest.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
@end

#import <OneSignal/OneSignal.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Replace '11111111-2222-3333-4444-0123456789ab' with your OneSignal App ID.
    [OneSignal initWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions
                               appId:@"xxxxxxx (my app id is here)"
            handleNotificationAction:nil
                            settings:@{kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: @false}];
    OneSignal.inFocusDisplayType = OSNotificationDisplayTypeNotification;

    // Recommend moving the below line to prompt for push after informing the user about
    //   how your app will use them.
    [OneSignal promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse:^(BOOL accepted) {
        NSLog(@"User accepted notifications: %d", accepted);
    }];

    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = self;
    // Call syncHashedEmail anywhere in your iOS app if you have the user's email.
    // This improves the effectiveness of OneSignal's "best-time" notification scheduling feature.
    // [OneSignal syncHashedEmail:userEmail];

    return YES;
}

-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void
                                                                                                                               (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    // iOS 10 will handle notifications through other methods

    if( SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO( @"10.0" ) )
    {
        NSLog( @"iOS version >= 10. Let NotificationCenter handle this one." );
        // set a member variable to tell the new delegate that this is background

       //this block here gets called when I debug

        return;
    }
    NSLog( @"HANDLE PUSH, didReceiveRemoteNotification: %@", userInfo );

    // custom code to handle notification content

    if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive )
    {
        NSLog( @"INACTIVE" );
        completionHandler( UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData );
    }
    else if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground )
    {  
        NSLog( @"BACKGROUND" );  
        completionHandler( UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData );  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        NSLog( @"FOREGROUND" );  
        completionHandler( UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData );  
    }  
}

@end
```

I need 'didReceiveNotificationExtensionRequest' since I'm trying to use iOS 10's mutable content feature. I've put in breakpoints and am sure that didReceiveNotificationExtensionRequest is never called, I'm wondering if I need to hook up the class somewhere else because the .m file never does anything. Any help appreciated

If it matters my phone is running ios 10.0 (so should support the mutable content) and OneSignal version is (2.5.4)
Thanks

Comment: Same was here. Tried to do it in Swift. The extension did not get called. As OneSignal forum states: when content-available is set to true, extension won't get called. I've turned content-available off, mutable content on. I could catch the notification and change the content. The structure differs. Eg.: additionalData can be reached as ```
let url = ((userInfo["custom"] as? [String: Any])?["a"] as? [String: Any])?["url"] as? String
```

Comment: yes, same issue, the oneSignal doc for react-native doesn't seem uptodate.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 10 `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method will not be called...you should go for

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler
```